# Assign a value to Bitset

Tags: c++, c++11, bitset

I'm curious to know why the following code is working!
According to bitset template class, you can assign a value to bitset (int or binary representation as string) by constructor but not after that.
But here you can see that explicit assign of a integer works fine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bitset<8> b(string("101"));
    cout << b.to_ullong()<<"\n";
    b= 145;
    cout << b<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

this question also might be relevant.
[How to assign bitset value from a string after initializaion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17360953/how-to-assign-bitset-value-from-a-string-after-initializaion)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bitset's [non-string constructors are implicit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/bitset/).

If they were declared as explicit you would indeed have to write

```
b = bitset<8>(145);
```

Comment: you mean that 145 is a constructor in above? I suppose that here = operator must have been overloaded and this is not a constructor call.
but I can not see any overload for = in your reference

Comment: @Sami1202 no. I meant that 145 is automatically converted into a bitset<8>. That has nothing to do with the assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

What might seem confusing is the fact that `std::bitset` does not explicitly define `operator=`. Compiler will, however, generate one (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943958/conditions-for-automatic-generation-of-default-copy-move-ctor-and-copy-move-assi) question). You can actually check that using [cppinsight](https://cppinsights.io/s/0f19f028). This means that, in combination with the implicit constructor mentioned in the accepted answer, your code works. You can see the constructor call and subsequent assignment in the cppinsight example.